# Remove previously placemark from mkmapview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a item list table. When I select a row of my table, I show a view with more information and a map with the placemark. 
The used code is below:

```c
MKCoordinateRegion region;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = {lat,longt};
region.center.latitude = coordinate.latitude;
region.center.longitude = coordinate.longitude;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.3;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.3;
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

MKPlacemark *mPlacemark = [[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil] autorelease];
[mapView addAnnotation:mPlacemark];
[mPlacemark release];
```

The problem is that when I select another item after the previously selected item in my map displays the new placemark and those previously. How to remove the previously placemark from my map??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with removing the previously added placemark.

```
- (void)removeAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
```

Like :
Declare `mPreviousPlacemark` as the `retain` property of your class.

```
[mapView removeAnnotation:mPreviousPlacemark];
[mapView addAnnotation:mPlacemark];
 self.mPreviousPlacemark = mPlacemark;
[mPlacemark release];
```

Comment: with this when I select for the second time a new item, the application crashes, but the console doesn't show any error.

Comment: @reb2awrl  : Could you show ?, How you have declared `mPreviousPlacemark` in **.h** ? and Have you used the `@synthesize` with `mPreviousPlacemark` , like  **@synthesize mPreviousPlacemark** in your **.m** class.

Comment: Yes I declared mPreviousPlacemark in .h and in .m file I used the @synthesize mPreviousPlacemark. After in viewWillAppear i have modified my previous code with your code.

Comment: the console don't show any error. I commented this line of code [mapView removeAnnotation:mPreviousPlacemark]; and the application does not crash

Comment: @reb2awrl  ... I Got the solution   Don't make  `MKPlacemark` as `autorelase`.   Should be **MKPlacemark *mPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil];**

Comment: ok now it's works!! :-) But why autorelease gave me an error? Thanks for everything!